# Javascript delay closing numeric keyboard on IOS

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios

I have two input fields(type="tel"). As the first input field is filled, then the focus will be set on the second input field.

The problem is on IOS that as you enter one number in the first input; the numeric keyboard closes before the focus goes on the second input field..

The code looks like that:

```
// the view
<input id='firstInput' type='tel'/> 
<input id='secondInput' type='tel'/>

//JS
$('#firstInput').on('input', function() { 
    $('#secondInput').focus();
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/6bSX6/2179/

This will work on android but on IOS.

I assume to delay closing the numeric keyboard would be the solution. How can I delay closing the keyboard on IOS? Any other suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Use the blur event instead of input :)

Comment: That doesn't help.. I guess it 's just timing issue..

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
$('#firstInput').on('blur', function() { 
    $('#secondInput').focus();
});
```

Comment: Hope this solution helped you.\